# fetching different data from one function

Tags: ios, swift

I am fetching data for different json models from multiple functions:

```
func fetchMovies(from moviesUrl: String, _ completion: @escaping (NowPlayingResponse?) -> Void){
    
    guard let safeUrl = URL(string: moviesUrl + apiKey) else {return}
    let alamofireRequest = AF.request(safeUrl)
    
    alamofireRequest.responseDecodable(of: NowPlayingResponse.self, decoder: jsonDecoder){ response in
        
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            guard let safeMovies = response.value else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            completion(safeMovies)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}

public func fetchGenres(from genresUrl: String, _ completion: @escaping (GenresResponse?) -> Void) {
    guard let safeUrl = URL(string: genresUrl + apiKey) else {return}
    let alamofireRequest = AF.request(safeUrl)
    
    alamofireRequest.responseDecodable(of: GenresResponse.self, decoder: jsonDecoder){ response in
        
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            guard let safeGenres = response.value else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            completion(safeGenres)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to make one function which will handle all types so it made my code cleaner:

```
func fetchMovies<T: Codable>(from moviesUrl: String, _ completion: @escaping (T?) -> Void){
    
    guard let safeUrl = URL(string: moviesUrl + apiKey) else {return}
    let alamofireRequest = AF.request(safeUrl)
    
    alamofireRequest.responseDecodable(of: T.self, decoder: jsonDecoder){ response in
        
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            guard let safeMovies = response.value else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            completion(safeMovies)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

When I called function to fetch data:

```
func getMoviees(){
    MovieServiceAPI.shared.fetchMovies(from: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing") { (moviesResponse) in
        guard let safeMovies = moviesResponse?.results else {return}
        self.movieList = safeMovies
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
            hideLoader()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting *Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred* error. I tried to put *MovieServiceAPI.shared.fetchMovies<NowPlayingReponse: Codable>* where *NowPlayingResponse* represents json model for data. Where am I getting wrong?

Comment: When you try the call, you specify nowhere what's `T`. It can't guess. A possible solution would be to do `{ (moviesResponse: NowPlayingResponse) in` to help the compiler understand what's the value of `T`. Another solution would be to put `T` as a parameter. The same way you can call yourself `JSONDecoder.decode(T.self, data: data)` you use it as a parameter explicitly. See the definition of the method to know more.

Comment: Problem solved with first solution. Thank you!